# Ubuntu not booting after upgrade to 12.04 from 11.10

Tags: boot, upgrade, boot-failure

I upgraded to 12.04 from 11.10 today. After the upgrade, I did the usual reboot of the system and then Ubuntu hangs on `Checking battery state..[OK]`. I can login to terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-F5` and I did `startx` but it hangs after displaying white images of the desktop icons..there is no menu or any top bar at all. I guess this problem has something to do with Xserver, but I cannot find xorg.conf on my system.

How can I get around this problem? Also is there a way I can make a backup of my files through the command line, because the GUI is not showing up at all?

Answer (score 1):

First up all boot with a live cd or usb (if it is available) and back up all your files.It seems that the  problem u have is related to the graphics driver.And another suggestion is that u run the recovery mode from the boot menu and fix any broken issues then come back to the normmal mode.Pls go through the known issues of this release too as your system specification has not provided. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop

Answer (score 1):

There might be many reasons for that. In my case, I chose gdm during upgrade, which seems to be not working properly under 12.10. To change to lightdm:

1. Press CTRL+F1
2. Login
3. Type "sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm" and choose the lightdm
4. reboot